# Easier way to input Dynamic matrix?

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation

I've only been using MMA for a month, and I'm working on making interactive Linear Algebra examples that will be used online for students.  Right now, for inputting numbers into a matrix, I've been using `PopupMenu` since it is simple to use and more stable then `InputField` for my application.

I currently just manually enter an array of PopupMenus:

```
inputA = {{PopupMenu[Dynamic[a11], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a12], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a13]},
          {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a21], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a22], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a23]},
          {PopupMenu[Dynamic[a31], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a32], Range[-9,9]],PopupMenu[Dynamic[a33]}};
```

One downside to `PopupMenu` is that it is too "cluttered" when the `Range` is too large. I haven't found any better ways of inputting values, but I was wondering if anyone had suggestions for alternatives for inputting values.

Also, is there is a more concise way of coding in MMA for making this input array?

Comment: Would it be an option to just let them type 2D input as normal, using Control-Enter and Control-Comma?  The problem is that they need to know how to do this ...

Comment: Concise way: `Clear[a];
Array[
  (a[##] = 1; PopupMenu[Dynamic[a[##]], Range[-9, 9]]) &, {3, 
   3}] // MatrixForm`, then use the matrix as `Array[a, {3,3}]`, e.g. display it as `Dynamic@MatrixForm@Array[a,{3,3}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs your concise version will work perfectly, thank you! Also, I think I'll just stick to the current input method since there will be a decent amount of usage (students throughout USA) and that could cause more problems

Comment: Can you tell more about why you find InputFields unstable?

Comment: @Kuba I (recent mech. engineering grad) inherited this project from a Computer Science guy in the company who used `InputField` initially, but when he input fractions or just erased what was inside the field, the rest of the application would break. So he told me to use `PopupMenu` instead, and I kind of just assumed he knew what he was talking about.  It is highly possible that he was just missing something (like `Number`) but I never actually took the time to check since I was brand new to the language.

Comment: @J_Nat I see, that's true the PopupMenu reduces things user may break but at a price of flexibility or crudity. Up to you, if you feel more comfortable with using menus at the beginning it is ok too.

Comment: InputField can be bulletproofed too but it requires more time probably, depeding of the type of the input field too

Comment: @Kuba I think the simplicity of clicking the mouse opposed to using the key board to plug numbers in is why I'll stick to what I'm using now. Also I'm done with over half of the examples so to go back and change what I've done doesn't sound appealing :)

Comment: @J_Nat sure, whatever fits your needs and available time.

Answer (score 2):

**This Exemple calculate Dynamicly a Determinant with PopupMenu:**

```
{MatrixForm[Array[(a[##]=0;     
PopupMenu[Dynamic[a[##]],Range[0,9]])&,{3,3}]],     
Dynamic[d=Table[Table[a[j,i],{i,1,3}],{j,1,3}];Det[d]]}
```

[image]

Useful for students